# Do sparse graphs have to be large?

Tags: graphs, terminology

I'm looking for a good definition of sparse graphs. Is a sparse graph effectively a big one, with millions/billions of nodes? An example from real world is the Facebook graph. Or can sparse graphs be in small networks as well?

Comment: Did you already check [the Wikipedia entry?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph)

Comment: given the above comment, removing the question might be a wise idea, unless you have some reason to be dissatisfied with the wikipedia answer. In that case, you should explain why.

Comment: @Juho I did, and it does not seem to contain a definition of "sparse".

Answer (score 5):

The common definition is that a *family* of graphs $G = (V, E)$ is sparse if $m \in o(n^2)$, with $n = |V|$ and $m = |E|$. Formally, that requires the family to be infinite, and we only know something *in the limit*.

The definition does not apply to graphs of a fixed size per se. One would certainly want $m \ll n^2$ in some sense. For instance, if $m \leq 5n$ or $m \approx \log n$ you would probably say that your graph is "sparse".

You can bridge this gap by requiring a bit more on the asymptotic side. Say we call a family of graphs sparse if

$\qquad\displaystyle m \leq f(n) + O(1)$ with $f \in o(n^2)$;

then we may want to call every graph with $m \leq f(n)$ sparse. The implicit assumption is that the error term hidden in $O(1)$ is well-behaved.

Comment: That said, I think people *want* smallish graphs to be "sparse" or "dense", but they got so used to abusing Landau notation to not notice that they don't give a definition for graphs of fixed size. In the folklore department, at least; the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_graph) references definitions that work for all sizes, but I've never seen or heard anyone use them. (Disclaimer: I'm not a member of a research community that regularly deals with sparse graphs.)

Answer (score 3):

Sparsity is a fuzzy notion, and its meaning will depend on the context. It can be argued a graph is not sparse "by itself", but rather it is sparse relative to other graphs. Indeed, there are several ways to define or measure sparseness.

We can say a connected graph is maximally sparse if it is a tree. Intuitively, a tree-like graph is sparse. But what could be a "tree-like graph"? Perhaps the number of cycles is bounded, or by removing a constant number of vertices we get a tree. One very popular definition of sparseness rises from these considerations. Informally, the [*treewidth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) of a graph is a measure of how close a graph is to being a tree.

To address your question, a graph of low treewidth can be either small or large. For instance, forests, trees, and outerplanar graphs all have constant treewidth. In contrast, a complete graph on $n$ vertices has treewidth $n-1$. This corresponds to our intuition that complete graphs are *not* sparse.

Treewidth is just one measure of sparseness. You can dig deeper into the literature and explore other measures as well.

Answer (score 2):

A graph is dense if the number of edges is closer to the maximum number of edges there could be. Formally, a graph is dense if $e=\cal \Omega(v^2)$ where $v,e$ are the number of vertices and edges. A graph is sparse if the above is not true.